# one child class method is calling another child class of same parent in python

Tags: python, inheritance

**Main objective is to create a "Stock_by_Material" method which will iterate over the amount of each item of a given material that is in stock. the script should add up to 10 cotton Polo shirts.**

```
class Clothing:
  stock={ 'name': [],'material' :[], 'amount':[]}
  def __init__(self,name):
    material = ""
    self.name = name
  def add_item(self, name, material, amount):
    Clothing.stock['name'].append(self.name)
    Clothing.stock['material'].append(self.material)
    Clothing.stock['amount'].append(amount)
  def Stock_by_Material(self, material):
    count=0
    n=0
    for item in Clothing.stock['material']:
      if item == material:
        count += Clothing.stock['amount'][n]
        n+=1
    return count

class shirt(Clothing):
  material="Cotton"
class pants(Clothing):
  material="Cotton"
  
polo = shirt("Polo")
sweatpants = pants("Sweatpants")
polo.add_item(polo.name, polo.material, 4)
sweatpants.add_item(sweatpants.name, sweatpants.material, 6)
current_stock = polo.Stock_by_Material("Cotton")
print(current_stock
```

Though the program above is giving the desired result i.e current _stock = 10.
As this code is written by someone else, I just filled some blanks...I am not able to understand why this person called Stock_by Material method on only "polo"...why not "clothing.Stock_by_material."
and why just calling "polo" is adding both "polo" and "sweatpants"

Comment: `Stock_by_Material` doesn't add anything, `add_item` does.

Comment: You are correct. add_item adds the products.  Stock_by_Material shows stock of all child class objects i.e shirt and pants having same materials....like cotton. My point is why polo.Stock_by_Material("Cotton") is showing items of polo and sweat pants together..